# Can you change which subversion repository a client is logged in to?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

On my laptop, I use the computer's name when accessing my svn repository (e.g. svn://computername/repository) with tortoise svn. However, when I'm outside of my network, I need to use an Internet addressable name (e.g. svn://computername.dyndns.com/repository). I would like to continue to do it this way, so that when I'm at home my checkins and updates are as fast as possible and are not dependent on another server being up (dyndns). Is there a way to use the same folder structure that I already have checked out and just change the name back and forth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Under the TortoiseSVN right-click menu, select 'Relocate'. You can change the URL of the repository from there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the fully qualified URL (e.g. svn://computername.dyndns.com/repository) from inside and outside of your network and not have to change at all.

Comment: Right, hence the part of my question talking about speed and being independent of other servers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to keep it in a centralized location so others can access you will have to keep a remote server like the way you do.

If you are the only user you con setup a svn repository in your own machine.

The bottleneck is the remote access, if you have to keep it up, changing the name you use to access wont make any difference.

Finally, if the issue is simply the relocating, you could setup your networks DNS to point computername.dyndns.com to computername and always access using the dyndns url.